# Trying to simplify complex sentences with modals

Tags: grammar

When I am writing a complex sentence using a modal verb, is it acceptable to move the second verb, so that less advanced readers don't have to wait until the end to find it?

Example: (this is my translation of a Canadian history textbook - if there is something wrong with the German feel free to comment as well!)

Könige und Prinzen sollen das Wissen über den wahren Gott verbreiten, durch die Bekehrung zu Katholizismus von einer unbegrenzten Anzahl von Wilden, die ohne Glaube, ohne Gesetz und ohne Wissen über den wahren Gott leben.

**instead of**

Könige und Prinzen sollen das Wissen über den wahren Gott durch die Bekehrung zu Katholizismus von einer unbegrenzten Anzahl von Wilden verbreiten, die ohne Glaube, ohne Gesetz und ohne Wissen über den wahren Gott leben.

*English text: Kings and princes ought to spread the knowledge of the true God by converting to Catholicism an infinite number of savages, who live without faith, without law and with no knowledge of the true God.*

Any and help is appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It can't be "Bekehrung zum Katholizismus einer unbegrenzten Anzahl von Wilden".
Rather: "Bekehrung einer unbegrenzten Anzahl von Wilden zum Katholizismus" (#)

Additionally, the **relative clause** *usually* has to come after the described word, so the translation (without moving the second verb) would be:

> Könige und Prinzen sollen das Wissen über den wahren Gott durch die Bekehrung einer unbegrenzten Anzahl von Wilden, **die ohne Glauben, ohne Gesetz und ohne Wissen über den wahren Gott leben**, zum Katholizismus verbreiten.

This entirely destroys melody and structure - mostly because # and the [Satzklammer](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satzklammer) should not be separated by too many words.

And that is exactly the argument you can use twice to justify:

> Könige und Prinzen sollen das Wissen über den wahren Gott verbreiten,  durch die Bekehrung einer unbegrenzten Anzahl von Wilden zum Katholizismus, die ohne Glauben, ohne Gesetz und ohne Wissen über den wahren Gott leben.

This is quite common in spoken language.

---

One could argue that it is not clear what the **relative clause** is referring to, so alternatively:

> Könige und Prinzen sollen das Wissen über den wahren Gott verbreiten, indem sie eine unbegrenzte Anzahl von Wilden, die ohne Glauben, ohne Gesetz und ohne Wissen über den wahren Gott leben, zum Katholizismus bekehren.

In this case "Bekehrung" and "zum Katholizismus" are closely together, you don't have to worry about where to put "verbreiten", and the (second degree) relative clause starts right after "Wilden". Minor flaw: first degree relative clause is very long. But hey: http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/5248/13.